# int4range, NOT IN (VALUES), ON NOT (with LEFT JOIN) in QueryDSL 4

Tags: postgresql, querydsl

I would like to know, how to make a `int4range / NOT IN (VALUES) / ON NOT (with LEFT JOIN)` in QueryDSL 4.
I've writte this SQL request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (numero_semaine, jour_semaine)
numero_semaine, jour_semaine, heure_debut, heure_fin, id_box
FROM (

    SELECT po.* FROM (

        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (numero_semaine, jour_semaine)
        numero_semaine, jour_semaine, heure_debut, heure_fin, id_box
            FROM accueil.semaine_type_box
            INNER JOIN accueil.plage_ouverture
            ON accueil.plage_ouverture.id_semaine_type = accueil.semaine_type_box.id_semaine_type
            INNER JOIN accueil.semaine_type
            ON accueil.semaine_type.id = accueil.semaine_type_box.id_semaine_type
            INNER JOIN accueil.box
            ON accueil.box.id = accueil.semaine_type_box.id_box
            WHERE semaine_type_box.numero_semaine >= 48
            AND semaine_type_box.numero_semaine <= 52
            AND (numero_semaine, jour_semaine)
            ---->NOT IN (VALUES (48,1), (48,2), (48,3), (48,4), (52,6), (52,7))<----
            AND semaine_type.site = 'UR130'
            AND box.ouvert_cotisant = TRUE
            ORDER BY numero_semaine, jour_semaine, heure_debut
        )

        UNION ALL

        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (numero_semaine, jour_semaine)
            extract(week from plage_exceptionnelle.date) as numero_semaine,
            extract(isodow from plage_exceptionnelle.date) as jour_semaine,
            heure_debut, heure_fin, id_box
            FROM accueil.plage_exceptionnelle
            INNER JOIN accueil.box ON
            accueil.box.id= accueil.plage_exceptionnelle.id_box 
            WHERE plage_exceptionnelle.date >= '2018-11-30'
            AND plage_exceptionnelle.date <= '2018-12-28'
            AND ouverte = TRUE
            AND box.site = 'UR130'
            AND box.ouvert_cotisant = TRUE
            ORDER BY numero_semaine, jour_semaine, heure_debut
        )
    ) po

    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            extract(week from plage_bloquee.date) as numero_semaine,
            extract(isodow from plage_bloquee.date) as jour_semaine,
            heure_debut, heure_fin, id_box
            FROM accueil.plage_bloquee
            INNER JOIN accueil.box ON accueil.box.id = accueil.plage_bloquee.id_box 
            WHERE box.site = 'UR130'
            AND box.ouvert_cotisant = TRUE
    ) pb

    ---->ON NOT(po.jour_semaine = pb.jour_semaine<----
    ---->AND int4range(po.heure_debut, po.heure_fin) && int4range(pb.heure_debut, pb.heure_fin)<----
    AND po.id_box = pb.id_box
    AND po.numero_semaine = pb.numero_semaine
    )

    WHERE pb.id_box IS NOT NULL

) end_table

ORDER BY numero_semaine,jour_semaine,heure_debut
```

What is the way to do this SQL request ?

I've writte this, but I don't find the way to writte a not in, on not with left join, and int4range doesn't exist with QueryDSL 4 :

```
    public List<PlageDisponibleWS> findDayAvailableDao(String organisme, String site, MediaEnum media) {

        final LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
        final short startWeekOfWeekYear = (short) startDate.getWeekOfWeekyear();
        final short startDay = (short) startDate.getDayOfWeek();

        final LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusMonths(1);
        final short endWeekOfWeekYear = (short) endDate.getWeekOfWeekyear();

        final int MONDAY_START_DAY = 1;
        final int TUESDAY_START_DAY = 2;
        final int WEDNESDAY_START_DAY = 3;
        final int THURSDAY_START_DAY = 4;
        final int FRIDAY_START_DAY = 5;
        final int SATURDAY_START_DAY = 6;
        final int SUNDAY_START_DAY = 7;

        PostgreSQLQuery<Tuple> plagesOuvertes = queryFactory
                    .select(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine, qSemaineTypeBox.idBox, qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine,
                            qPlageOuverture.heureDebut, qPlageOuverture.heureFin)
                    .distinctOn(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine, qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine).from(qSemaineTypeBox)
                    .innerJoin(qPlageOuverture).on(qPlageOuverture.idSemaineType.eq(qSemaineTypeBox.idSemaineType))
                    .innerJoin(qSemaineType).on(qSemaineType.id.eq(qSemaineTypeBox.idSemaineType)).innerJoin(qBox)
                    .on(qBox.id.eq(qSemaineTypeBox.idBox)).where(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine.goe(startWeekOfWeekYear))
                    .where(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine.loe(endWeekOfWeekYear))
                    // NOT IN (VALUES (startWeekOfWeekYear,MONDAY_START_DAY), (startWeekOfWeekYear,TUESDAY_START_DAY),
                    // (startWeekOfWeekYear,WEDNESDAY_START_DAY), (startWeekOfWeekYear,THURSDAY_START_DAY),
                    // (endWeekOfWeekYear,SATURDAY_START_DAY), (endWeekOfWeekYear,SUNDAY_START_DAY)) ??
                    .where(qSemaineType.site.eq(site)).where(qBox.ouvertCotisant.eq(true))
                    .orderBy(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine.asc(), qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine.asc(),
                            qPlageOuverture.heureDebut.asc());

            PostgreSQLQuery<Tuple> plagesExceptionnelles = queryFactory
                    .select(qPlageExceptionnelle.date.week().as("numero_semaine"),
                            qPlageExceptionnelle.date.dayOfWeek().as("jour_semaine"), qPlageExceptionnelle.heureDebut,
                            qPlageExceptionnelle.heureFin, qPlageExceptionnelle.idBox)
                    .distinctOn(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine, qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine).from(qPlageExceptionnelle)
                    .innerJoin(qBox).on(qBox.id.eq(qPlageExceptionnelle.idBox))
                    .where(qPlageExceptionnelle.date.goe(startDate)).where(qPlageExceptionnelle.date.loe(endDate))
                    .where(qPlageExceptionnelle.ouverte.eq(true)).where(qBox.site.eq(site))
                    .where(qBox.ouvertCotisant.eq(true)).orderBy(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine.asc(),
                            qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine.asc(), qPlageOuverture.heureDebut.asc());

            PostgreSQLQuery<Tuple> plagesBloquees = queryFactory
                    .select(qPlageBloquee.date.week().as("numero_semaine"),
                            qPlageBloquee.date.dayOfWeek().as("jour_semaine"), qPlageBloquee.heureDebut,
                            qPlageBloquee.heureFin, qPlageBloquee.idBox)
                    .from(qPlageBloquee).innerJoin(qBox).on(qBox.id.eq(qPlageBloquee.idBox)).where(qBox.site.eq(site))
                    .where(qBox.ouvertCotisant.eq(true));

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Expression<Tuple> unionSubQuery = queryFactory.query().unionAll(plagesOuvertes, plagesExceptionnelles)
                    .as("po");

            final PathBuilder<Object> aliasPb = new PathBuilder<>(Object.class, "pb");

            PostgreSQLQuery<Tuple> leftJoinSubQuery = queryFactory.select(unionSubQuery)
                    .leftJoin(plagesBloquees, aliasPb)
                    // ON NOT
                    // INT4RANGE
                     ;

            final PathBuilder<Object> aliasEnd = new PathBuilder<>(Object.class, "end_table");

            query = queryFactory
                    .select(Projections.constructor(PlageDisponibleWS.class, qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine,
                            qSemaineTypeBox.idBox, qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine, qPlageOuverture.heureDebut,
                            qPlageOuverture.heureFin))
                    .distinctOn(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine, qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine)
                    .from(leftJoinSubQuery, aliasEnd).orderBy(qSemaineTypeBox.numeroSemaine.asc(),
                            qPlageOuverture.jourSemaine.asc(), qPlageOuverture.heureDebut.asc())
                    .fetch();

        return query;
}
```

So please have you any idea to solve my problems ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "in values" construction with multiple columns you can try this:

```
.where(list(table.column1, table.column2).
    in(list(select(constant("aaa"), constant("bbb")),
        select(constant("ccc"), constant("ddd")),
        select(constant("eee"), constant("fff")))))
```

Function "list" and "select comes from these imports:

```
import static com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions.*;
import static com.querydsl.sql.SQLExpressions.*;
```

For "left join + not", try this:

```
.from(table1)
.leftJoin(table2)
.on(table1.id.ne(table2.id))
```

Unfortunatly I am not familar with int4range function, hovewer you can try to use template expression for custom database functions:

```
Expressions.template(Integer.class, "custom_db_function({0}, {1})", 10, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks Piotr, in + list + select works perfectly and left join + on + ne too.

For int4range, I have a problem, Expressions.template is not applicable with the method and, I've tried this :
`.and(Expressions.template(Short.class, "int4range({0}, {1}) && int4range({2}, {3})", po.get(heure_debut), po.get(heure_fin), pb.get(heure_debut), pb.get(heure_fin)))`
But I have an error :
"The method and(Predicate) in the type BooleanExpression is not applicable for the arguments (SimpleTemplate<Short>)"
Have you any idea to solve this ?

Comment: For where condition you need to use templates that return boolean value. For what values returned by `int4range({0}, {1}) && int4range({2}, {3})` condition, template should return true? You can try changing declaration of template to `Expressions.template(Boolean.class...` - this will convert 0 to false, and other values to true (if I remeber correctly).

Comment: You can try also to wrap value returned by template by case expression: `.and(Expressions.template(...).when((short) 0).then(false).when((short) 1).then(false).otherwise(true)`

Comment: One more idea - try to use `Expressions.booleanTemplate(...)` instead `Expressions.template(Boolean.class, ...)`

Comment: Perfect ! 
`Expressions.booleanTemplate(...)` works perfectly.
Thank you so much, you saved me !!